# RegEx for for string that has bezier<somestring>Path

Tags: regex

I have a large file in xCode that contains numerous occurrences of bezierPath (ie bezier456Path). What I'd like to do is come up with a regular expression for this string so I can replace it simply with the string "bezierPath". I've tried things like bezier\w*Path to no avail. Does anyone know what I could use to search for a string like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` is for word characters.  Based on your example, you need to search for digits (`\d`):

```
bezier\d+Path
```

Also, since your replacement string is `bezierPath`, there is no point in using `*` (i.e. zero or more), since that would include replacing `bezierPath` with itself.  Therefore, you should use `+` (i.e. one or more), instead.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider Glad I could help!  Please mark my solution as answered when you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to xcode, but can't you use Find with

```
(bezier.*?Path)
```

and then use Replace with the path that you want, so in this case just bezierPath